# Console.log not showing anything in Chrome Console. (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]So I am just starting out with React but facing an issue if someone would be kind enough to resolve it.
My **index.js** code is:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const element= 'Hello world'
console.log(element)
```

The Code above should show "Hello World" when I open the browser and inspect the element but it shows nothing. The tutorial I am watching has "Hello World" showing up. Can someone look into this for me? Thank you

P.S: I have added a picture which shows my code layout in VScode

Comment: without any info on your setup this is hard to answer, but are you sure that this file is actually being included in your code (i.e. as an `import` or a javascript tag in the HTML?)

Comment: If you aren't getting anything in your console, then this code isn't getting executed. But we can't say why.  Are you including this code in your page?

Comment: I just checked and this may sound weird but the code above works fine when open in Pycharm but fails to show output in the console when run with Visual Studio Code

Comment: If you want this question answered, please tell us a bit more how you're running this, and how you are including this file. Also, how are you running it in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: I have added a picture which shows my code, Maybe that will help

Comment: Are you using `create-react-app`?

Comment: npx create-react-app.
This code

Comment: This was only an issue because the OP didn't save their file in the editor.  Voting to close as not-reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

use statement terminator after declaring const element="hello wolrd"; and write to console

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for the confusion, Apparently, Pycharm saves the file automatically whereas, in VScode, The auto-save feature has been disabled or isn't there. I save my code on VScode using Ctrl+S and now the result is showing in the browser. Thank you, everyone, for the replies